# Get a Value In between a date stored as a decimal

Tags: sql, decimal, between

I'm working with a database where dates are stored as decimal values. For example, 9/1/2019 is stored as 20190901.

In my select statement, I can cast the field to look like a regular date. However, when I try to use BETWEEN, values outside the range still show up.

```
select distinct balanceDate, cast(CAST(balanceDate AS VARCHAR(8)) as date)AS 
balDate 
from balanceTable
where balanceDate BETWEEN '20190301' AND '20190901'
```

Result: rows with a balanceDate of 20191031 appear.

Should I maybe use the cast in the where clause?

Comment: So field ```balanceDate``` is of some integer type or is it a varchar (perhaps of fixed length)? What DBMS are you running?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Date values should be stored in columns defined as `DATE` not decimal or varchar or anything else. The problem you have, is a direct result of that bad design decision

Comment: You need to confirm the datatype of your BalanceDate column. You say it's a decimal, but you are comparing it to strings (`balanceDate BETWEEN '20190301' AND '20190901'`).

Comment: @Michelle . . . I cannot think of a situation where 20191031 could appear with those two boundaries, regardless of the types of the columns.  I suspect you simply mistyped the constants in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Havent used cast but below you could try if it works for you as

```
  select distinct TO_DATE(TO_CHAR( 
      balanceDate), 'YYYYMMDD')) 
     , 
   cast(CAST(balanceDate AS 
   VARCHAR(8)) as date)AS 
    balDate 
    from balanceTable
    where TO_DATE(TO_CHAR( 
      balanceDate), 'YYYYMMDD')) 
     BETWEEN 
      '20190301' AND '20190901'
```

Comment: Use to_date to convert to a date type.

Comment: Read my answer again cant you see to_DATE in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply cast where part instead of select part

```
select distinct balanceDate, cast(CAST(balanceDate AS VARCHAR(8)) as date) AS balDate 
from balanceTable
where convert(varchar,CAST(balanceDate AS VARCHAR(8),112) BETWEEN '20190301' AND '20190901'
```

but please consider that using functions prevents index usage thus this query makes full table scan.

Note: The answer is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You have to stay consistent. If all your dates have int datatype then comparing ints is faster. Try:

```
select distinct balanceDate
from balanceTable
where balanceDate BETWEEN 20190301 AND 20190901
```